# Async getterMethods in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can get an async call in a getterMethod to work. Goal is that I have a model `wallet` and the wallet can have many `walletTransactions`. Goal is when `wallets` is queried, that it send a virtual field of name 'balance'.

I have tried the following:

```
getterMethods: {
      balance:  function() {
        return this.getWalletTransactions()
        .then((transactions) => {
          var balance = 0;
          transactions.forEach((value) => {
            balance = balance + value.amount;
          })
          return balance;
        })
      }
    }
```

But without any luck. The result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call `getterMethods.balance` function?

Comment: Wallet.find() - Nothing special

Comment: How do you use _result_ of this call? Just `let res = Wallet.find(); console.log(res);`?

Comment: return a promise => return Wallet.find()

Answer (score 6):

The `getterMethod` is synchronous so you would not be able to run a promise and return the resolved value on the model instance.

However, depending on your use case, you may be able to tie into the `afterFind` hook and run an asynchronous operation:

```
const Wallet = db.define('wallet', {...}, {
  hooks: {
    afterFind: instances => {
      // instances is an array for the list view or an object for the detail view.
      if (Array.isArray(instances)) {
        performAsyncOperation()
          .then(data => {
            // loop over instances
          });        
      } else {
        performAsyncOperation()
          .then(data => {
            instances.dataValues.someNewProp = data.someField
          });        
      }
    }
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do here is have your getter return the promise. The problem is that you might expect property `balance` to be a number, but it will actually be a promise for that number.

You can do exactly what you're doing and say `yourInstance.balance.then(theThingYouWant => { /* ... */ });`

But, this isn't a very established pattern.